# Replace commas with wrapped div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have code like this. And would like to replace the , and wrap each word in a div. And adding line-breaks would be a plus.

```
<div class="utility">
Analysis,Arrears/Final Notice Communications,Automated Legal Processing
</div>
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
<div class="utility">
<div class="something">Analysis</div><div class="something">Arrears/Final Notice Communications</div><div class="something">Automated Legal Processing</div>
</div>
```

Is this possible with Javascript? And How? Thanks in advance

Im adding this in Wordpress in the Footer script to run.

Someone suggested this [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442848/how-to-wrap-each-word-in-a-span-but-retain-text-formatting) but did not work for me:

```
$('.hero_image p').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).html().split(' '),
        len = text.length,
        result = []; 

    for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        result[i] = '<span>' + text[i] + '</span>';
    }
    $(this).html(result.join(' '));
});
```

Comment: Are you restricted to plain JavaScript, or is it possible to use a framework like React, Vue.js, or Angular? I know these frameworks come with some overhead that may be unacceptable for certain use cases, but their [templating capabilities](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html) (specifically [list rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)) make easy work of this problem.

Comment: Numerous [existing solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+wrap+each+word) on SO